# Connection times out for wget and npm and so on

Tags: networking, 22.04, wget

I just installed a Ubuntu 22.04 on my computer. It has not worked very good so far. For some reason it is very slow with installing packages and commands like:

`wget http://google.com` times out all the time.

I also have constant problem with npm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74736078/npm-install-takes-forever-says-i-am-behind-a-proxy

When I run `wget http://google.com` on my Mac I get an instant response. The only difference is that my Ubuntu computer is connected through a wire.

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be annoying for others. I found this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94074/slow-wget-speeds-when-connecting-to-https-pages

and using `--inet4-only` did the trick.

The next step was to go into advanced network settings and disable IPv6:

[image]